# Emacs mode to edit JSON

Tags: json, emacs, unicode

Does anybody know a good Emacs mode to edit JSON? An app I am working on uses a JSON based communication protocol and having the data nicely indented and syntax-highlighted would help me a lot in the process of figuring it out.

Comment: see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24855/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-or-not-a-string-is-valid-json/ I use js2-mode to validate JSON

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried Steve Yegge's [js2-mode for Emacs](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/)?

Comment: JSON is not really supported by js2-mode, though.
http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/issues/detail?id=50

Comment: @Török Gábor: Do you know a better alternative?

Answer (score 36):

+1 for Josh's [json-mode](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/json-mode) -- works well for me.  I added

```lisp
(defun beautify-json ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((b (if mark-active (min (point) (mark)) (point-min)))
        (e (if mark-active (max (point) (mark)) (point-max))))
    (shell-command-on-region b e
     "python -m json.tool" (current-buffer) t)))
```

and

```lisp
(define-key json-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-f") 'beautify-json)
```

to json-mode.el to make the shell command invocation easier.

**UPDATE:**  For those of you with a need/desire to do this with unicode, see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924515/unicode-conversion-issue-using-python-in-emacs).  The upshot is rather than using:

```sh
python -m json.tool
```

you will want to use

```sh
python -c 'import sys,json; data=json.loads(sys.stdin.read()); print json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True,indent=4).decode("unicode_escape").encode("utf8","replace")'
```

This both beautifies the JSON as well as preserving the original Unicode content.

Comment: fwiw, I forked'd Josh's json-mode and added jstevenco's addition to it at https://github.com/chad3814/json-mode

Comment: I have requested a fix for the non-ASCII udate at https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode/issues/5

Comment: The latest version of json-mode has now fixed the utf-8 issue: see https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode/issues/5

Comment: This all works out the box installing the latest [json-mode package](http://melpa.org/#/json-mode) on [melpa](http://melpa.org/#/). Nice work guys.

Comment: do not use `"unicode_escape"` with json content. [Use `ensure_ascii=False` instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407/4279)

Answer (score 30):

**js-mode supports syntax highlighting and indentation for json files.**

This is as of Emacs **23.2**, when espresso-mode was incorporated into Emacs and renamed js-mode.

Check it out:
http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/

Comment: Nice! I put `(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("\\.json\\'" . js-mode) auto-mode-alist))` in my `.emacs`

Comment: `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.json$" . js-mode))` is the same thing but a little shorter.

Answer (score 15):

If you want something lightweight try this major-mode I hacked together: https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode

It's actually no more than some extra syntax highlighting on top of javascript-mode, but for my purposes I've found it to work quite well.

Another common use-case is auto-formatting a JSON file (eg. if it's whitespace-compressed and you want more readability).  To do this I'm just piping the buffer through a command-line script: C-u M-|

Comment: fwiw, I forked this repo and added jstevenco's beautify-json function, and it's at https://github.com/chad3814/json-mode - also sent a pull request.

Comment: FWIW Josh accepted Chad's pull request to include jstevenco's addition (got all that?) so as of this writing [Josh's json-mode repo on github](https://github.com/joshwnj/json-mode) is the most up-to-date source for json-mode.

Comment: Pleaes apply the non-ASCII fix.

Comment: Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17319/4003 (I load json-mode in my .emacs)

Answer (score 9):

I've prepared a workaround for [js2-mode](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/) so it parses json files without errors.
You can find it in my comment: http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/issues/detail?id=50#c7

(I wanted to post it as a comment do J.F. Sebastian solution, but it seems I'm not allowed to do so (no 'add comment' link))

Answer (score 6):

`json.el` by Edward O'Connor is part of GNU Emacs since 23.1 (2008).

While it isn't a syntax highlighter, it has a useful function to format JSON:

```
M-x json-pretty-print-buffer RET
```

So, if you have a recent version of Emacs, there is no need for `jq` or `python -m json.tool`.

Comment: Using `json-pretty-print-buffer` included with GNU Emacs 24.5.1, I have found that while it nicely formats my JSON, it also reverses its content. Fortunately, I also found that running it a second time on my JSON restores it to its original order.

Answer (score 3):

Since JSON is a subset of YAML, `yaml-mode` works too (I don't know how it compares to `js-mode` and `json-mode`, though).

Install (from emacs): `M-x package-install yaml-mode`.

Association of `yaml-mode` with YAML and JSON files, in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.yaml$" . yaml-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.json$" . yaml-mode))
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is supported by [espresso-mode](http://www.nongnu.org/espresso/)

Comment: I can only get espresso-mode to work with legal Javascript syntax.  JSON expressions don't, for example, get indented properly.

Comment: Espresso has been incorporated into GNU Emacs starting with version 23.2 and has been renamed js-mode. espresso-mode will no longer be maintained outside of Emacs proper.

Answer (score 0):

js3-mode:https://github.com/thomblake/js3-mode

js3-mode is an improved js2-mode

This package can be installed by package-list-packages command

Answer (score 0):

I will also second Josh's json-mode, but also recommend flymake-json as an addition. It helps highlight syntax errors.

I don't like using `python -mjson.tool` because it reorders items in JSON objects.
I find `(prog-indent-sexp)` works just fine to reindent, and using `jsonlint`
instead of `python -mjson.tool` works for pretty printing/reformatting in `beautify-json`

```
(eval-after-load "json-mode"
  '(progn
     (require 'flymake-json)
     ;; flymake-cursor displays error in minibuffer message area instead of requiring hover
     (require 'flymake-cursor)

     (add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'flymake-json-load)
     (define-key json-mode-map "\C-c\C-n" (function flymake-goto-next-error))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've expanded on Mariusz Nowak's [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841588/1713079), to make it usable as a major mode in its own right. Little modification was required beyond simply deriving the mode; the only change Nowak's work actually needed was the ability to recognize buffers not associated with files, or associated with files whose names don't end in `.json`, as JSON, which we accomplish with a buffer-local variable.

Here's the augmented workaround:

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'js2-parse-as-json)

(defadvice js2-reparse (before json)
    (setq js2-buffer-file-name buffer-file-name))
(ad-activate 'js2-reparse)

(defadvice js2-parse-statement (around json)
    (if (and (= tt js2-LC)
           js2-buffer-file-name
           (or js2-parse-as-json
               (string-equal (substring js2-buffer-file-name -5) ".json"))
           (eq (+ (save-excursion
                    (goto-char (point-min))
                    (back-to-indentation)
                    (while (eolp)
                      (next-line)
                      (back-to-indentation))
                    (point)) 1) js2-ts-cursor))
      (setq ad-return-value (js2-parse-assign-expr))
        ad-do-it))
(ad-activate 'js2-parse-statement)

(define-derived-mode json-mode js2-mode "JSON"
  "Major mode for editing JSON data."
  :group 'json
  (setq js2-parse-as-json t)
  (js2-reparse t))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.json$" . json-mode))
```

If you already use js2-mode, this may be a better option than `js-mode` plus `flymake-json` because you need not install anything new (js2-mode already does syntax checking, no need for an external tool), and because this mode will inherit your js2-mode configuration, which js-mode will not.

Answer (score -8):

I would also recommand js2-mode.

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. It's not another language and it's even not a data container like yaml or xml are. JSON could be used as a data container if there's no function (or in this case we should say method) inside a JSON object, but it's not the primary goal of JSON :-)

```
var myJSObject = {
  attr: {foo: "bar", baz: ["quux", "truc", "pouet"]},
  fooAlert: function (num) {
    alert(this.attr.foo+' '+num);
  }
};
myJSObject.fooAlert(42);
```

Comment: To be exact, the example you provided ain't JSON but the JavaScript object literal, which is similar but different.

Comment: Another language that is a data container like YAML or XML is exactly what JSON is, actually, and JSON does not allow functions.