# Troubles in printing unicode string that I have in byte format

Tags: python, byte, python-unicode

Reading from a database I get the following value

`b'd\xe2\x80\x99int'`

How can I print it to get the string `d’int` (note that this is different from `d'int`)?

I tried with `print(b'd\xe2\x80\x99int'.decode('utf-8'))` but I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

EDIT: thanks to the comment I understood that the problem is not in my Python code but in emacs, I am having exactly the same problem as described here [Unicode conversion issue using Python in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924515/unicode-conversion-issue-using-python-in-emacs)

I will close the question

Comment: Your code works for me, without error.

Comment: @Nisba How can we reproduce your error? This line `print(b'd\xe2\x80\x99int'.decode('utf-8'))` won't raise any exception

Comment: You are right, in my terminal it works. I get the error running it inside emacs, either if I print it on the shell console inside emacs either in a file. So maybe my Python process in emacs must be told to accept unicode strings

Comment: @Nisba Does set `PYTHONIOENCODING` env.var to `utf-8` makes any difference when spawning python process on your emacs console or whatever emacs uses to display text?

Comment: I am trying to change its value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

```
>>> bytes.decode(b'd\xe2\x80\x99int', 'utf8')
'd’int'
```

or analogously, the `.decode()` method over the bytes object itself:

```
>>> b'd\xe2\x80\x99int'.decode('utf-8')
'd’int'
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately the problem is not in the code, see the edit