# Saving UTF-8 texts with json.dumps as UTF-8, not as a \u escape sequence

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8, escaping

Sample code (in a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop)):

```
import json
json_string = json.dumps("ברי צקלה")
print(json_string)
```

Output:

```
"\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9 \u05e6\u05e7\u05dc\u05d4"
```

The problem: it's not human readable. My (smart) users want to verify or even edit text files with JSON dumps (and I’d rather not use XML).

Is there a way to serialize objects into UTF-8 JSON strings (instead of `\uXXXX`)?

Comment: This is often used as a duplicate for questions where the proper answer is really "JSON is a format for information interchange, not for human consumption; forcing it to use UTF-8 will not work in all cases, and you should probably not try".

Comment: You've got Hebrew there. Specifically for RTL languages like Hebrew, this is a bad idea, because of how Unicode handles bidirectional text. What do you think are the keys and associated values in `{"a": "ב", "בב": "b"}`? It's not what it looks like - `"a"` is a key with value `"ב"`, and `"בב"` is a key with value `"b"`. How about ``{"a ב": "בב"}``? There, the key is `"a ב"` and the value is `"בב"`. People are *not* going to reliably get this right.

Comment: @user2357112 this is a matter of text viewer / editor.  some editors work well with it, some not.  The software doesn't care.  So it's irrelevant; There are even worse cases of usability e.g. empty space characters, or control characters. All valid JSON dict keys, and ... well, that's not the issue.

Comment: "There are even worse cases of usability e.g. empty space characters, or control characters." - normal ASCII spaces are fine. If someone's got control characters and weird non-ASCII spaces, those are just more reasons for them not to do what you're looking for, but you posted Hebrew, so I focused on the problems that specifically arise with Hebrew.

Comment: Also see section 9 of [ECMA-404](https://ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf).

Answer (score 1286, accepted):

Use the `ensure_ascii=False` switch to `json.dumps()`, then encode the value to UTF-8 manually:

```
>>> json_string = json.dumps("ברי צקלה", ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
>>> json_string
b'"\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99 \xd7\xa6\xd7\xa7\xd7\x9c\xd7\x94"'
>>> print(json_string.decode())
"ברי צקלה"
```

If you are writing to a file, just use `json.dump()` and leave it to the file object to encode:

```
with open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    json.dump("ברי צקלה", json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

**Caveats for Python 2**

For Python 2, there are some more caveats to take into account. If you are writing this to a file, you can use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead of `open()` to produce a file object that encodes Unicode values for you as you write, then use `json.dump()` instead to write to that file:

```
with io.open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    json.dump(u"ברי צקלה", json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Do note that there is a [bug in the `json` module](http://bugs.python.org/issue13769) where the `ensure_ascii=False` flag can produce a *mix* of `unicode` and `str` objects. The workaround for Python 2 then is:

```
with io.open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data = json.dumps(u"ברי צקלה", ensure_ascii=False)
    # unicode(data) auto-decodes data to unicode if str
    json_file.write(unicode(data))
```

In Python 2, when using byte strings (type `str`), encoded to UTF-8, make sure to also set the `encoding` keyword:

```
>>> d={ 1: "ברי צקלה", 2: u"ברי צקלה" }
>>> d
{1: '\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8\xd7\x99 \xd7\xa6\xd7\xa7\xd7\x9c\xd7\x94', 2: u'\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9 \u05e6\u05e7\u05dc\u05d4'}

>>> s=json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8')
>>> s
u'{"1": "\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9 \u05e6\u05e7\u05dc\u05d4", "2": "\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9 \u05e6\u05e7\u05dc\u05d4"}'
>>> json.loads(s)['1']
u'\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9 \u05e6\u05e7\u05dc\u05d4'
>>> json.loads(s)['2']
u'\u05d1\u05e8\u05d9 \u05e6\u05e7\u05dc\u05d4'
>>> print json.loads(s)['1']
ברי צקלה
>>> print json.loads(s)['2']
ברי צקלה
```

Comment: The roundtrip `encode`/`decode` doesn't seem to be necessary. Just setting `ensure_ascii=False` (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40585572/2025495)) seems to be enough.

Comment: @AdamAL please read my answer more thoroughly: there is no round trip in this answer, apart from a decode call that’s only there to demonstrate that the bytes value indeed contains UTF-8 encoded data. The second code snippet in my answer writes directly to a file, only setting `ensure_ascii=False`. Note: I strongly recommend against using the `codecs.open()` function; the library predates `io` and the stream implementations have a lot of unresolved issues.

Comment: @AdamAL In 3.x, setting `ensure_ascii=False` is sufficient because *the result from `.dump` or `.dumps` is already a string*. Any encoding task is handled already by the encoding setting for the destination file (if applicable).

Answer (score 155):

To write to a file

```
import codecs
import json

with codecs.open('your_file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump({"message":"xin chào việt nam"}, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

To print to stdout

```
import json
print(json.dumps({"message":"xin chào việt nam"}, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file json-utf8.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was that simple. You only need to be careful if the data you are converting to json is untrusted user input.

Comment: @Alex That's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xa3-in-file-when-function-returns-%c2%a3

Answer (score 32):

[Pieters' Python 2 workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-with-json-dumps-as-utf-8-not-as-a-u-escape-sequence/18337754#18337754) fails on an edge case:

```
d = {u'keyword': u'bad credit  \xe7redit cards'}
with io.open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).decode('utf8')
    try:
        json_file.write(data)
    except TypeError:
        # Decode data to Unicode first
        json_file.write(data.decode('utf8'))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It was crashing on the .decode('utf8') part of line 3.   I fixed the problem by making the program much simpler by avoiding that step as well as the special casing of ASCII:

```
with io.open('filename', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
  data = json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8')
  json_file.write(unicode(data))

cat filename
{"keyword": "bad credit  çredit cards"}
```

Comment: The 'edge case' was simply a dumb untested error on my part. Your `unicode(data)` approach is the better option rather than using exception handling. Note that the `encoding='utf8'` keyword argument has nothing to do with the output that `json.dumps()` produces; it is used for decoding *`str` input* the function receives.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: or simpler: `open('filename', 'wb').write(json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'))` It works whether `dumps` returns (ascii-only) str or unicode object.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: right, because `str.encode('utf8')` *decodes* implicitly first. But so does `unicode(data)`, if given a `str` object. :-) Using `io.open()` gives you more options though, including using a codec that writes a BOM and you are following the JSON data with something else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `.encode('utf8')`-based variant works on both Python 2 and 3 (the same code). There is no `unicode` on Python 3. Unrelated: json files should not use BOM (though a confirming json parser may ignore BOM, see [errate 3983](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=7159)).

Comment: adding `encoding='utf8'` to `json.dumps` solves the problem. P.S. I have a cyrillic text to dump

Answer (score 31):

This is the wrong answer, but it's still useful to understand why it's wrong. See comments.

Use `unicode-escape`:

```
>>> d = {1: "ברי צקלה", 2: u"ברי צקלה"}
>>> json_str = json.dumps(d).decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8')
>>> print json_str
{"1": "ברי צקלה", "2": "ברי צקלה"}
```

Comment: `unicode-escape` is not necessary: you could use `json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')` instead. And it is not guaranteed that json uses *exactly the same* rules as `unicode-escape` codec in Python in *all* cases i.e., the result might or might not be the same in some corner case. The downvote is for an unnecessary and possibly wrong conversion. Unrelated: `print json_str` works only for utf8 locales or if `PYTHONIOENCODING` envvar specifies utf8 here (print Unicode instead).

Comment: Another issue: any double quotes in string values will lose their escaping, so this'll result in *broken JSON output*.

Comment: error in Python3 :AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: unicode-escape works fine! I would accept this answer as correct one.

Comment: @jfs No, `json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')` is not working, for me at least. I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position ...`-error. The `unicode-escape` variant works fine however.

Comment: @turingtested the error is likely in your other code. It is hard to say without a minimal complete code example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, even though it's wrong in OP's case, it definitely pointed me in the right direction for serializing JSON for consumption by Postgres' COPY FROM STDIN command (this was driving me nuts !!)

Answer (score 30):

As of Python 3.7 the following code works fine:

```
from json import dumps
result = {"symbol": "ƒ"}
json_string = dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
print(json_string)
```

Output:

```
{"symbol": "ƒ"}
```

Comment: also in python 3.6 (just verified).

Comment: worked well without further complexity..

Answer (score 30):

Thanks for the original answer here. With Python 3 the following line of code:

```
print(json.dumps(result_dict,ensure_ascii=False))
```

was ok. Consider trying not writing too much text in the code if it's not imperative.

This might be good enough for the Python console. However, to satisfy a server, you might need to set the locale as explained here (if it is on Apache 2)
*[Setting LANG and LC_ALL when using mod_wsgi](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html)*

Basically, install he_IL or whatever language locale on Ubuntu.
Check it is not installed:

```
locale -a
```

Install it, where XX is your language:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-XX
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-he
```

Add the following text to */etc/apache2/envvrs*

```
export LANG='he_IL.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='he_IL.UTF-8'
```

Then you would hopefully not get Python errors on from Apache like:

> print (js)
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 41-45: ordinal not in range(128)

Also in Apache, try to make UTF the default encoding as explained here:
*[How to change the default encoding to UTF-8 for Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913869/how-to-change-the-default-encoding-to-utf-8-for-apache)*

Do it early because Apache errors can be pain to debug and you can mistakenly think it's from Python which possibly isn't the case in that situation.

Answer (score 13):

#### Use *unicode-escape* to solve the problem

```
>>>import json
>>>json_string = json.dumps("ברי צקלה")
>>>json_string.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
'"ברי צקלה"'
```

#### Explanation

```
>>>s = '漢  χαν  хан'
>>>print('Unicode: ' + s.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8'))

Unicode: \u6f22  \u03c7\u03b1\u03bd  \u0445\u0430\u043d

>>>u = s.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
>>>print('Original: ' + u.encode("utf-8").decode('unicode-escape'))

Original: 漢  χαν  хан
```

Original resource：*[Python3 使用 unicode-escape 处理 unicode 16进制字符串编解码问题](https://blog.csdn.net/chuatony/article/details/72628868)*

Comment: That's silly use the library's built-in feature `ensure_ascii=False` instead of rolling your own. (But understand that saving JSON as bare UTF-8 can introduce interoperability problems, especially on Windows.)

Comment: @tripleee its not silly - its the only solution that gives the exact result which is a similar encoding to file write with utf-8.

Comment: thanks :) it helped me to convert a response i received with text to convert it to german readable text

Answer (score 8):

The following is my understanding var reading answer above and google.

```
# coding:utf-8
r"""
@update: 2017-01-09 14:44:39
@explain: str, unicode, bytes in python2to3
    #python2 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
    #1.reload
    #importlib,sys
    #importlib.reload(sys)
    #sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') #python3 don't have this attribute.
    #not suggest even in python2 #see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script
    #2.overwrite /usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py or (sitecustomize.py and PYTHONPATH=".:$PYTHONPATH" python)
    #too complex
    #3.control by your own (best)
    #==> all string must be unicode like python3 (u'xx'|b'xx'.encode('utf-8')) (unicode 's disappeared in python3)
    #see: http://blog.ernest.me/post/python-setdefaultencoding-unicode-bytes

    #how to Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence
    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence
"""

from __future__ import print_function
import json

a = {"b": u"中文"}  # add u for python2 compatibility
print('%r' % a)
print('%r' % json.dumps(a))
print('%r' % (json.dumps(a).encode('utf8')))
a = {"b": u"中文"}
print('%r' % json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False))
print('%r' % (json.dumps(a, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')))
# print(a.encode('utf8')) #AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'
print('')

# python2:bytes=str; python3:bytes
b = a['b'].encode('utf-8')
print('%r' % b)
print('%r' % b.decode("utf-8"))
print('')

# python2:unicode; python3:str=unicode
c = b.decode('utf-8')
print('%r' % c)
print('%r' % c.encode('utf-8'))
"""
#python2
{'b': u'\u4e2d\u6587'}
'{"b": "\\u4e2d\\u6587"}'
'{"b": "\\u4e2d\\u6587"}'
u'{"b": "\u4e2d\u6587"}'
'{"b": "\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87"}'

'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
u'\u4e2d\u6587'

u'\u4e2d\u6587'
'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'

#python3
{'b': '中文'}
'{"b": "\\u4e2d\\u6587"}'
b'{"b": "\\u4e2d\\u6587"}'
'{"b": "中文"}'
b'{"b": "\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87"}'

b'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
'中文'

'中文'
b'\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
"""
```

Comment: The first sentence is incomprehensible. Can you [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41521794/edit)?

Answer (score 8):

If you are loading a JSON string from a file and the file content is Arabic texts, then this will work.

#### Assume a file like *arabic.json*

```
{
  "key1": "لمستخدمين",
  "key2": "إضافة مستخدم"
}
```

#### Get the Arabic contents from the *arabic.json* file

```
with open(arabic.json, encoding='utf-8') as f:
   # Deserialises it
   json_data = json.load(f)
   f.close()

# JSON formatted string
json_data2 = json.dumps(json_data, ensure_ascii = False)
```

#### To use JSON data in a Django template follow the below steps:

```
# If have to get the JSON index in a Django template file, then simply decode the encoded string.

json.JSONDecoder().decode(json_data2)
```

Done! Now we can get the results as a JSON index with Arabic values.

Comment: `fh.close()` `fh` is undefined.

Comment: IT's Corrected now. It would be ```f.close()```

Comment: You are using a context manager (`with open....`) so the `close` is unnecessary anyway. Python silently accepts it for now, but it's really an error, which could be exposed in a future version.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution using json.dump():

```
def jsonWrite(p, pyobj, ensure_ascii=False, encoding=SYSTEM_ENCODING, **kwargs):
    with codecs.open(p, 'wb', 'utf_8') as fileobj:
        json.dump(pyobj, fileobj, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,encoding=encoding, **kwargs)
```

where SYSTEM_ENCODING is set to:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
SYSTEM_ENCODING = locale.getlocale()[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use codecs if possible,

```
with codecs.open('file_path', 'a+', 'utf-8') as fp:
    fp.write(json.dumps(res, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: What is "codecs"? A Python package? What import statement is required for it? Something else? What is the advantage of using it? Why did you choose it? For instance, you could link to documentation for it. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51835456/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -4):

Using *ensure_ascii=False* in *json.dumps* is the right direction to solve this problem, as [pointed out by Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-with-json-dumps-as-utf-8-not-as-a-u-escape-sequence/18337754#18337754). However, this may raise an exception:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

You need extra settings in either *site.py* or *sitecustomize.py* to set your *sys.getdefaultencoding()* correct. *site.py* is under *lib/python2.7/* and *sitecustomize.py* is under *lib/python2.7/site-packages*.

If you want to use *site.py*, under def setencoding(): change the first if 0: to if 1: so that Python will use your operation system's locale.

If you prefer to use *sitecustomize.py*, which may not exist if you haven't created it, simply add these lines:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Then you can do some Chinese JSON output in UTF-8 format, such as:

```
name = {"last_name": u"王"}
json.dumps(name, ensure_ascii=False)
```

You will get an UTF-8 encoded string, rather than a \u escaped JSON string.

To verify your default encoding:

```
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

You should get "utf-8" or "UTF-8" to verify your *site.py* or *sitecustomize.py* settings.

Please note that you could not do *sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")* at an interactive Python console.

Comment: no. Don't do it. Modifying default character encoding has nothing to do with `json`'s `ensure_ascii=False`. Provide a minimal complete code example if you think otherwise.

Comment: You only get this exception if you either feed in non-ASCII *byte strings* (e.g. not Unicode values) or try to combine the resulting JSON value (a Unicode string) with a non-ASCII byte string. Setting the default encoding to UTF-8 is essentially masking an underlying problem were you are not managing your string data properly.