# UnicodeDecodeError while using json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I have strings as follows in my python list (taken from command prompt):

```
>>> o['records'][5790]
(5790, 'Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\xe1M1-2-\xe19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ', 60,
 True, '40141613')
>>>
```

I have tried suggestions as mentioned here: [Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python#comment2239381_2276222)

Further changed the default encoding to utf-16 too. But still `json.dumps()` threw and exception as follows:

```
>>> write(o)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "okapi_create_master.py", line 49, in write
    o = json.dumps(output)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 25: invalid
continuation byte
```

Can't figure what kind of transformation is required for such strings so that `json.dumps()` works.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`\xe1` is not decodable using utf-8, utf-16 encoding.

```
>>> '\xe1'.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: unexpected end of data
>>> '\xe1'.decode('utf-16')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_16.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 0: truncated data
```

Try latin-1 encoding:

```
>>> record = (5790, 'Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\xe1M1-2-\xe19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ',
...           60, True, '40141613')
>>> json.dumps(record, encoding='latin1')
'[5790, "Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\\u00e1M1-2-\\u00e19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ", 60, true, "40141613"]'
```

Or, specify `ensure_ascii=False`, `json.dumps` to make `json.dumps` not try to decode the string.

```
>>> json.dumps(record, ensure_ascii=False)
'[5790, "Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\xe1M1-2-\xe19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ", 60, true, "40141613"]'
```

Comment: The fastest way to remove the error by using `ensure_ascii=False`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and came up with the following approach to either guarantee unicodes or byte strings, from either input. In short, [include and use](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/84ac194c77f04817eeb3#file-stringext-py) the following lambdas:

```
# guarantee unicode string
_u = lambda t: t.decode('UTF-8', 'replace') if isinstance(t, str) else t
_uu = lambda *tt: tuple(_u(t) for t in tt) 
# guarantee byte string in UTF8 encoding
_u8 = lambda t: t.encode('UTF-8', 'replace') if isinstance(t, unicode) else t
_uu8 = lambda *tt: tuple(_u8(t) for t in tt)
```

Applied to your question:

```
import json
o = (5790, u"Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\xe1M1-2-\xe19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ", 60,
 True, '40141613')
as_json = json.dumps(_uu8(*o))
as_obj = json.loads(as_json)
print "object\n ", o
print "json (type %s)\n %s " % (type(as_json), as_json)
print "object again\n ", as_obj
```

=>

```
object
  (5790, u'Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\xe1M1-2-\xe19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ', 60, True, '40141613')
json (type <type 'str'>)
  [5790, "Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\u00e1M1-2-\u00e19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ", 60, true, "40141613"]
object again
  [5790, u'Vlv-Gate-Assy-Mdl-\xe1M1-2-\xe19/16-10K-BB Credit Memo            ', 60, True, u'40141613']
```

Here's some more [reasoning about this](https://gist.github.com/miraculixx/84ac194c77f04817eeb3#file-asciidecodeerror-py).