# json.dump - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, json, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a dictionary `data` where I have stored:

- `key` - ID of an event
- `value` - the name of this event, where `value` is a UTF-8 string

Now, I want to write down this map into a json file. I tried with this:

```
with open('events_map.json', 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump(data, out_file, indent = 4)
```

but this gives me the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0:
>   invalid start byte

Now, I also tried with:

```
with io.open('events_map.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
   out_file.write(unicode(json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8")))
```

but this raises the same error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 0:
>   invalid start byte

I also tried with:

```
with io.open('events_map.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
    out_file.write(unicode(json.dumps(data, encoding="utf-8", ensure_ascii=False)))
```

but this raises the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbf in position 3114: ordinal not in range(128)

Any suggestions about how can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
I believe this is the line that is causing me the problem:

```
> data['142']
'\xbf/ANCT25'
```

**EDIT 2:**
The `data` variable is read from a file. So, after reading it from a file:

```
data_file_lines = io.open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf8').readlines()
```

I then do:

```
with io.open('data/events_map.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Which gives me the error:

> TypeError: must be unicode, not str

Then, I try to do this with the data dictionary:

```
for tuple in sorted_tuples (the `data` variable is initialized by a tuple):
    data[str(tuple[1])] = json.dumps(tuple[0], ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8')
```

which is, again, followed by:

```
with io.open('data/events_map.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    json.dump(data, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

but again, the same error:

```
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

I get the same error when I use the simple `open` function for reading from the file:

```
data_file_lines = open(file_name, "r").readlines()
```

Comment: The string in your `data` dictionary is not actually UTF-8 encoded; decoding it to Unicode fails.

Comment: Can you please put the actual `data` dictionary in your post? Just include the output of `print data`.

Comment: The `data` variable is too big to paste it. Anyway, I think only one entry on my dictionary is causing the problem. I edited my post.

Comment: That string is indeed *not* UTF-8 encoded. Is that supposed to be an [inverted question mark](http://codepoints.net/U+00BF), perhaps?

Comment: You'll have to either replace that value with an actual UTF-8 encoded value, or replace it with a Unicode value (so explicitly decode it first before passing it to `json.dump()`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The exception is caused by the contents of your `data` dictionary, at least *one* of the keys or values is *not* UTF-8 encoded.

You'll have to replace this value; either by substituting a value that *is* UTF-8 encoded, or by decoding it to a `unicode` object by decoding just that value with whatever encoding is the correct encoding for that value:

```
data['142'] = data['142'].decode('latin-1')
```

to decode that string as a Latin-1-encoded value instead.

Comment: I read these values from a file. You were correct about the inverted question mark, so I changed that value with another UTF-8 character (the letter "é"). With your solution `data['142'].decode('latin-1')` it doesn't raise any errors, but in the final json file I have "142": "\u00e9ANCT25", instead of the expected: "142": "éANCT25". I tried to read the file with codecs.open(file_name, "r", "utf-8"), but here I have: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 2526468: invalid continuation byte`. How do I solve this prob. so the real characters are written in the json?

Comment: `\u00e9` is a valid JSON escape sequence; do you absolutely *have* to have the Unicode character instead of the JSON `\uxxxx` escape sequence?

Comment: @Belphegor: see [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18337754) for how to produce such data.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this didn't help me. It still doesn't work. I edited my question where I describe what else I've tried (in "Edit 2"). Any other suggestion?

Comment: Never mind, I've solved it finally! I got the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/write-json-data-to-file-in-python/14870531#14870531  (the code for Python 2.x). Anyway, @Martijn Pieters , I wouldn't have done it without you, so I am accepting your answer. But, please add the answer from the link I've provided in your answer, so it would be clearer if someone else bumps into the same problem. Cheers!

Comment: FYI: I already edited your answer with the final version of my code, but I don't know if it's going to be approved by the moderators. Anyway, tnx for the help!

Comment: Thanks, that answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/write-json-data-to-file-in-python/14870531#14870531 worked for me too!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while opening a simple text file. What worked for me was switching the open encoding to "latin1".