# Some readble content, but impossible to JSON dump to file

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8

This [text file](http://gget.it/3hgi8uyu/temp.txt) (30 bytes only, the content is `'(Ne pas r\xe9pondre a ce message)'`) can be opened and inserted in a `dict` successfully :

```
import json

d = {}

with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
   d['blah'] = f.read()

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    data = json.dumps(d)
    f.write(data)
```

But it is impossible to dump the `dict` into a JSON file (see traceback below). Why?

I tried lots of solutions provided by various SO questions. The closest solution I could get was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25122834/1422096). When using this, I can dump to file, but then the JSON file looks like this:

```
# test.txt
{"blah": "(Ne pas r\u00e9pondre a ce message)"}
```

instead of

```
# test.txt
{"blah": "(Ne pas répondre a ce message)"}
```

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is not UTF-8 encoded. It uses a *Latin* codec, like ISO-8859-1 or Windows Codepage 1252. Reading the file gives you the *encoded* text.

JSON however requires *Unicode* text. Python 2 has a separate Unicode type, and byte strings (type `str`) need to be decoded using a suitable codec. The `json.dumps()` function uses UTF-8 by default; UTF-8 is a widely used codec for encoding Unicode text data that can handle all codepoints in the standard, and is also the default codec for JSON strings to use (JSON *requires* documents to be encoding in one of 3 UTF codecs).

You need to either decode the string manually or tell `json.dumps()` what codec to use for the byte string:

```
data = json.dumps(d, encoding='latin1')  # applies to all bytestrings in d
```

or

```
d['blah'] = d['blah'].decode('latin1')
data = json.dumps(d)
```

or using `io.open()` to decode as you read:

```
import io

with io.open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='latin1') as f:
    d['blah'] = f.read()
```

By default, the `json` library produces ASCII-safe JSON output by using the `\uhhhh` escape syntax the JSON standard allows for. *This is entirely normal*, the output is valid JSON and readable by any compliant JSON decoder.

If you *must* produce UTF-8 encoded output without the `\uhhhh` escape sequences, see [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Comment: Thanks, but when using this, the output file looks like this : `{"blah": "(Ne pas r\u00e9pondre a ce message)"}`

Comment: @Basj: yes, because that's the proper JSON encoding of the data. See [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407) if you want to have the codepoint encoded to UTF-8 instead of using an escape sequence.

Comment: Arghh, this is annoying... I wanted to use JSON to have both 1) something that can be easily loaded into a dict in python  2) human readable in a Text editor... With all the `\u00*`, it won't be human readable anymore in a text editor. I won't be able to "search" for patterns like "répondre" with the standard search tool.

Comment: I already tried the last link that you gave https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence   in the past 2 hours ;) but unsuccessfully. How would it work here?

Comment: @Basj: the problem then is that your text editor needs to be consistently configured to handle UTF-8. Note also that the Unicode standard allows for codepoints to be *decomposed* into component parts; a `e` followed by a combining accent acute would display the same but would not necessarily be findable when searching for the `é` composed codepoint.

Comment: @Basj: `json.dumps(d, encoding='latin1', ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')` produces UTF-8 output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74408/discussion-between-basj-and-martijn-pieters).