# How to solve Flask jsonfify encoding/decoding?

Tags: python, json, flask

I am making some api. Now I have problems when want to render some non english characters in json. This is example:

`"Вук"` is show as `"\u0412\u0443\u043a"` in json output.
I see lot of people is having this problem but I can not find solution.

This is peace of code:

```
response = {
                "message":"user data",
                "data":{
                    "email":user.username+"@"+user.emaildomain,
                    "username":user.username,
                    "domain":user.emaildomain,
                    "first_name":user.firstname,
                    "last_name":user.lastname,
                    "created_at":user.created_at,
                    "birthday":user.birthdate
                },
                "status":1
            }

return jsonify({'response': response})
```

When I do print for example of `user.firstname` I can see correct string.

Solution(?)
I replaced `return jsonify(...)` with `return json.dumps({'response': response}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')`.

Thanks to this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337754/1108279 now i got correct output.

Comment: That's valid JSON output. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Perhaps you were looking for [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407) ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not see how to use that in my app. I am not saying that this is working output. I just need output to be same as from print.

Comment: Evidently you worked it out :-)