# XML to JSON with Hebrew Characters in Python

Tags: python, json, xml, ascii, hebrew

I'm trying to convert an xml with Hebrew characters in it, to json.

here's a piece of the xml:

```
     <Root><City>ירושלים</City></Root>
```

I've tried several methods and encodings, but I always get this unconvertable ascii code instead of Hebrew characters.:

> \u05e7\u05e0\u05d9\u05d5\u05df

Here's my conversion script:

```
import xmltodict, json
import sys

infile = open('text.xml','r')
outfile = open('text.json','w')
xmltxt = infile.read().decode('utf_16_le')

decodedXML = xmltodict.parse(xmltxt)

jsontext = json.dumps(decodedXML, encoding='utf_8')

outfile.write(jsontext.encode('utf_8'))
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Thank you

**EDIT - Solution:**
Solved by adding 'ensure_ascii=False' to json.dumps()

Comment: You have valid JSON; `\uhhhh` are JSON escape sequences used to keep your JSON output ASCII-safe. If you want UTF-8 output, see [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407)

Comment: You should not need to decode infile, the encoding should be part of the header. And you don't need to encode jsontext twice. It should already be a byte-string. The double encode is a nop, and looks like cargo-cult-programing.