# Json.dump() not working while streaming tweets

Tags: json, python-3.x, tweepy

Good morning everyone,
I'm having a rave with my twitter bot - I need to dump the streamed tweets (which arrive in json) to a file.
I previously have done this by writing it as utf8 formatted strings, however it now turns out that I still need to filter some data, so storing it away as json in the file seemed like the easiest way to go. 
I edited the code accordingly:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
import datetime
import json

access_token = #####
access_token_secret = ##### 
consumer_key = #####
consumer_secret =   ##### 

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status)
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        with open('/git/twttrbots/data/Twitter_Raw %s' %
                        today.strftime("%a-%Y-%m-%d"), 'a') as f:
            json.dump(status, f)  # <- doesn't work
            #f.write(json.dumps(status))  # <- doesn't work
            #f.write("Blah")    # <- works perfectly fine

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            #login using auth
            l = StdOutListener()
            auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
            auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
            stream = Stream(auth, l)

            #filter by hashtag
            stream.filter(track=['bitcoin', 'cryptocurrency', 'wonderlandcoin',
                                    'btc', 'fintech', 'satoshi', 'blockchain',
                                        'litecoin', 'btce'])
        except:
            print("Whoops, dicsonnected at %s. Retrying"
                    % datetime.datetime.now())
            continue
```

The file is created, the status definitely is read (there's print output in my terminal) but somewhere along the way my data is blasted out into nirvana, instead of my file - as that remains empty at `0` bytes.

I found similar cases [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309269/write-json-data-to-file-in-python) and on other platforms, however, they used `json.dumps()` instead of `json.dump()` - albeit I have tried both functions as well (using `f.write(dumps(status))`), but none of them seem to work.

Now, I'm not a complete fool; I am well aware that it's probably on my end - not a `JSON` error - but I can't figure out what it is i am doing wrong.

The only thing I was able to do, is boil it down to an error that occurs in my with `open()` statement, leading me to believe it's something about either the `open()` mode, or the way I write my data to the file. I know this, since the above linked question's answer works fine on my machine.

I could, of course, use the subprocess module and call a pipe that dumps the print(status) to a file, but that can't be the solution to this?

**Addendum**
As requested, here's my console [output](http://pastebin.com/FV81q0KY).

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/8k7F59xM) what the logger caught when I called `logger.debug('status dump: %s', json.dumps(status))`.

Comment: Can you log what the unencoded text looks like? It's possible that something in it invalidates the JSON format.

Comment: I added my print output as a pastebin link - i havent put any logging in my code before, but i will as soon as I have it implemented.

Comment: Added what my logfile says. this si the first time I use, and I'm not sure this is the right way to log it. If you have any pointers, I'm listening :/

Comment: There's a lot of information here to parse, but immediately I'd note that `json.dump` would throw errors for single quotes instead of doubles and for `False` not being in quotation marks. [This site](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) is helpful for testing JSON data for validity.

Comment: The data is valid coming out of the stream is definitely JSON - I dumped it to a file before using using the CLI; I then extracted the data using the JSON module (read by line and json.loads(line)), it may just be the print() messing it up? 
Hence my suspicion it has something to do with the write mode.
**edit**: Scratch the print() rambling; since dumping in CLI via '>' takes print()'s output, that can't be.

Comment: I repeal my previous statement - it's not working if I dump it via CLI anymore.  
But that still doesn't get me further down the road to a solution - So I know that for whatever reason the JSON format doesn't cut it - even though I directly pass it from the API to the module's dump function (I'm not touching it anywhere else).

 And since I am definitely not the only one using the tweepy library, or even streaming tweets from twitter, where is the error in my code? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An initial observation I have to make (because it got frustrating when I tried to run this script):

Don't make your except clauses too broad, you catch everything (Including `KeyboardInterrupt`) and make it hard to stop execution.

This is optionary, but it's good to add the appropriate interrupt:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

The second thing you are doing which is just making your life a bit harder is that not only are you catching everything using the bare `except`; you are not ***printing the corresponding error***. Adding this will catch the culprit in this case, point you to the right direction and make your life so much easier.

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
    print("Whoops, dicsonnected at %s. Retrying"
            % datetime.datetime.now())
```

This outputs a (***rather disgusting***) message which essentially prints out the `Status` object and ends with a line informing you that this object:

```
is not JSON serializable
```

This is somewhat logical since what we are dealing here isn't a `json` object but, instead, a `Status` object returned from `tweepy.Stream`.

I have no idea why exactly the creator(s) of `tweepy` have done this, a believe there's solid reasons behind it, but to ***solve your issue*** you can simply access the underlying `.json` object:

```
json.dump(status._json, f)
```

Now, you should be good to go.

---

### Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

This seems to be an internal `tweepy` issue relating to the transition from `Python 2` to `Python 3.x`. Specifically, in file ***`streaming.py`***:

```
File "/home/jim/anaconda/envs/Python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 171, in read_line
    self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size) <--
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

#### First probable solution:

There has been a solution proposed (and according to the replies, working) on the `tweepy` [GitHub](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/615) repository by user **cozos** suggesting:

> In ***streaming.py***:
>
> I changed line `161` to:
>
> > `self._buffer += self._stream.read(read_len).decode('ascii')`
>
> and line `171` to:
>
> > `self._buffer += self._stream.read(self._chunk_size).decode('ascii')`
>
> and then reinstalled.

Even though I'm not sure what he means by 'reinstalled'.

#### Second solution:

Use `tweepy` with `Python 2.7.10`. It works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'm no dumping via `json.dump(status._json, f)`, but the error now is:  `Error:  'str' does not support the buffer interface`. :/

Comment: I did find a useful pointer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence). 
it's still not 100% the data I want dumped, but it DOES dump data in general, so I consider my question answered. Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking into the error, If I find something useful I'll update my answer accordingly :-)

Comment: I edited my answer to include two alternate probable solutions. Check them out and if you have the energy, give em a shot.

Comment: I know about solution one, and actually have done that already; saved me tons of annoying encoding errors. But alas, that can't be it then. 
And regarding solution 2: Python 2 is the devil. Just kidding. I'll give it a shot, although we're trying not to code in 2.7 unless there is absolutely no other way. But I supposed im pretty close to that point. Thanks for the update!