# Django Rest Framework and Angular 2 File Upload

Tags: python, django, rest, angular, file-upload

I am using Django Rest Framework and Angular 2 to upload a file. My files looks like this. 
What do I do wrong? Tell me please. Thank you very much.

**Django file:**

*view*

```
class ProjectTaskViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProjectTask.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectTaskSerializers
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer, format=None):
        file = self.request.data.get('file', False)
        if file:
            serializer.save(
                text=serializer.validated_data.get('text'),
                project=serializer.validated_data.get('project'),
                file=file)
        else:
            serializer.save(
                text=serializer.validated_data.get('text'),
                project=serializer.validated_data.get('project')
            )

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        project = self.request.query_params.get('project', False)
        if project:
            queryset = queryset.filter(project_id=project)
        return queryset
```

*serializers*

```
class ProjectTaskSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProjectTask
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return ProjectTask.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

*model*

```
class ProjectTask(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(_('text'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        _('file'), blank=True, null=True, upload_to=directory_path
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        DashboardProject,
        verbose_name=_('project'),
        related_name='task_list',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('project task')
        verbose_name_plural = _('project tasks')
        ordering = ('-id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:20]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<ProjectTask {}>'.format(self.text[:20])
```

**Angular files**

*component*

```
saveTask() {
    this.taskForm.value.file = this.file;
    console.log(this.taskForm.value);
    this.taskService.addTask(this.file).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }

  onChange(event) {
    let files = event.target.files;
    console.log(files);
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);
    //if (files.length > 0) {
    //  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    //  for (let file of files) {
    //    formData.append('files', file, file.name);
    //  }
    console.log(formData);
    this.file = formData
  }
```

*service*

```
  addTask(model:any): Observable<TaskId> {

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
      // headers.set('Authorization', 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
      // headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data' );
      // headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
      headers.set('Content-Type', '*/*' );
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.post(URL, model, options).map((response: Response) => response.json());

  }
```

*input*

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" formControlName="file" (change)="onChange($event)">
```

Comment: Do you encounter any errors? If yes, please post them!

Comment: Object { _body: "{"detail":"Multipart form parse error - Invalid boundary in multipart: None", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Object, type: 2, url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task/" }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MultiPartParserError :- Invalid boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326150/multipartparsererror-invalid-boundary)

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this:
angular2-service(set the content type you need: [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html#mime-types-list)):

```
  uploadFile(file, filename: string){
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});
headers.append("X-CSRFToken", this.utils.getCookie('csrftoken'));
headers.append("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.put(this.connectorsUrl + 'manage-files/', file , options)
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

In django view:

```
    def put(self, request, format=None):

    file_obj = request.FILES['file']

    self.logger.info('Uploading file')
    uploaded = bicloudreposervice.upload_file(request.user.username, file_obj)

    return out
```

If you want to use TempFiles handler add to settings:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
```

]