# Python encoding and json dumps

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I apologize if this question has been asked earlier. I am still not clear about encoding in python3.2.

I am reading a csv(encoded in UTF-8 w/o BOM) and I have French accents in the csv.

Here is the code to opening and reading the csv file:

```
csvfile = open(in_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
fieldnames = ("id","locale","message")    
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,fieldnames,escapechar="\\") 
for row in reader:
        if row['id'] == id and row['locale'] == locale:
            out = row['message'];
```

I am returning the message(out) as Json

```
jsonout = json.dumps(out, ensure_ascii=True)    
return HttpResponse(jsonout,content_type="application/json; encoding=utf-8")
```

However when I preview the result I get the accent e(French) being replaced by \u00e9 .

Can you please advice on what I am doing wrong and what should I do so that the json output shows the proper e with accent.

Thanks

Comment: *“However when I preview the result I get the accent e(French) being replaced by \u00e9.”* – That sounds right to me. What is your question?

Comment: yeah if you do `print('\u00e9')` in python it prints out é so the representation is correct. If you are seeing `\u00e9` that just means that the program you are seeing it in doesn't understand the accent.

Comment: The httpResponse prints out the response as \u00e9. I waould like to know what change do i need to make so that the response prints out e with accent.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-with-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong (and neither is Python).

Python's json module simply takes the safe route and escapes non-ascii characters. This is a valid way of representing such characters in json, and any conforming parser will resurrect the proper Unicode characters when parsing the string:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'Crêpes': 5})
'{"Cr\\u00eapes": 5}'
>>> json.loads('{"Cr\\u00eapes": 5}')
{'Crêpes': 5}
```

Don't forget that json is just a representation of your data, and both `"ê"` and `"\\u00ea"` are valid json representations of the string `ê`. Conforming json parsers should handle both correctly.

It is possible to disable this behaviour though, see the [`json.dump` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage):

```
>>> json.dumps({'Crêpes': 5}, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"Crêpes": 5}'
```

Comment: Cool Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @tkansara: and if you really want to change the default, you can, Python doesn't prevent you from producing full-on UTF-8. See [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407)

Answer (score 3):

In respect to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337754/2395605), setting `ensure_ascii=False` renders the special characters in your printouts. On the other hand, [marcelm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35582727/2395605) is still correct, as no information is lost in those encodings.

Comment: Changing to false puts Ã© instead of e with accent.

Comment: interesting. I tested it and it worked fine for me. might be though, that I used python 3.5.