# json.dump() in Python 2.7 dumps text encoded

Tags: python-2.7

I have a web scraper application that scraps some Japanese site. The site has UTF-8 encoded Japanese characters. For example,

```
2017-03-02 17:14:17,862 - __main__ - DEBUG - 出演者: 青山茉利奈
2017-03-02 17:14:17,862 - __main__ - DEBUG - 作者: ひつき
2017-03-02 17:14:17,862 - __main__ - DEBUG - 収録時間: 123分
```

As you can see, when I do `logger.debug()` in the code, the characters are printed on screen correctly. But when I use `json.dump()` to dump this data in a json text file, the strings are encoded to something like

> "\u53ce\u9332\u6642\u9593": "123\u5206",

This is not what I want. What I want is exactly what I see in the debug log. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This has been answered on the site before, here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18337754/1759987

Comment: The solution in this link works. I dump the object to a json string, and then save it to a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Answer (score -1):

```
json.dumps(whatever, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Specify `ensure_ascii=False` to disable `\u` escaping. Note that if the presence of this escaping is actually causing you problems, whatever code needs to receive this JSON is broken.

Comment: Thanks, now I get 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-26: ordinal not in range(128)`