# Python: Get rid of Java-Escapes in JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7, escaping

Requesting a REST-API with the python requests package I got a JSON-string that is full of Java-Escapes. E.g. it uses `\u00f6` instead of `ö`. I could replace each escape-string with the respective character, but I suppose there are much better solutions.

Here is my code:

```
data = requests.get(url,auth=auth, headers=headers)
parsed = json.loads(data.content)
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(parsed,outfile,indent=4,sort_keys=True)
```

There is a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence) but i did not succeed trying to adapt it to my problem.

EDIT: This is a snippet of the output:

```
"address": {
    "quarter": "Niedersch\u00f6nhausen (Pankow)", 
    "street": "Blankenburger Stra\u00dfe", 
    "wgs84Coordinate": {
        "latitude": 52...., 
        "longitude": 13....
        }
}
```

Comment: This question could really use a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.  In this case, showing the strings that are not what you expected could be helpful

Comment: Thank you. I added a piece of the output.

Comment: It's not a "java-escape", it's a JSON syntax: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf And it's a JSON parser responsibility to parse it accordingly. Any standard-compliant parser would just work fine http://ideone.com/ffmbmm

Comment: So the string is exactly as expected from the `json.dumps()`.  What is your use case?  What do you need the output of `json.dumps()` to be used for?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your quick responses! My purpose is to convert it to GeoJSON to display it on a webmap. So i suppose this won't be a problem with the JSON parser. By mistake i thought this encoding was an error.