# dict to Cyrillic string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have dict with data

```
{'Credit Card': 'No', u'Room (0): \u0411\u044e\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0435\u0445\u043c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440': {'Info': {'Info': u'\u041f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043d\u0435 \u0432\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0432 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u0443 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0430.  \u0420\u0430\u0437\u043c\u0435\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439 \u0438 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043a\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0439: \u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0435\u0448\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0432\u043e\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0430. \u041f\u0440\u0438 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u043c\u0435\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0438 \u0434\u043e \u0434\u0432\u0443\u0445 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439  \u043c\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0448\u0435 6 \u043b\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0438\u043c\u0435\u044e\u0449\u0438\u0445\u0441\u044f \u043a\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044f\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0438\u043c \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e . \u0414\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043a\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0432 \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0435 \u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f.  \u041f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430: \u041f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043d\u0435  \u0432\u0437\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f.  \u041f\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0434\u043e\u043a \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f: \u0412 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0438\u0437\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0432 \u0441\u0440\u043e\u043a \u0434\u043e 18:00 \u0434\u0430\u0442\u044b \u0437\u0430\u0435\u0437\u0434\u0430 \u0448\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0444 \u043d\u0435 \u0432\u0437\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f. \u0412 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0438\u0437\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0437\u0434\u043d\u0435\u0435 \u044d\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0441\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430 \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0432 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435 \u043d\u0435\u0437\u0430\u0435\u0437\u0434\u0430 \u0432\u0437\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f 100 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432 \u043e\u0442  \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u043e\u0439 \u043d\u043e\u0447\u0438 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f . '}, 'Guest': u'\u0421\u0418\u041b\u042c\u0412\u0415\u0421\u0422\u0420 \u0421\u0422\u0410\u041b\u041e\u041d\u0415', 'Smoking people': 'No', 'Daily rates': ['2018-02-20: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)', '2018-02-21: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)', '2018-02-22: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)', '2018-02-23: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)'], 'Number of guests': '2', 'Price details': [u'\u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043d\u0430\u043b\u043e\u0433: 10.0RUB (included in room daily rates)'], 'Meal': u'\u041f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043d\u0435 \u0432\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0432 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u0443 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0430. '}, 'ChannelHotelId': '2360119', 'Channel reservation id': '1884282051', 'Commission': '1194.00'}
```

how can I convert it Cyrillic string ?

Comment: This is a dictionary with a perfectly valid Cyrillic Unicode string. What's the problem?

Comment: when I save it to Django and then try to view it in browser I don't get Cyrillic, but same weird symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - this is valid Unicode string, if you just `print(your_dictionary)` you should see Cyrillic text (at least that works for me).

Now the part about saving it to Django, I assume that you store it as json string, so all you need to do is properly dump it into json string:

```
import json
d = {'Credit Card': 'No', u'Room (0): \u0411\u044e\u0434\u0436\u0435\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0442\u0440\u0435\u0445\u043c\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440': {'Info': {'Info': u'\u041f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043d\u0435 \u0432\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0432 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u0443 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0430.  \u0420\u0430\u0437\u043c\u0435\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439 \u0438 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u043a\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0439: \u0420\u0430\u0437\u0440\u0435\u0448\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439 \u043b\u044e\u0431\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0432\u043e\u0437\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0430. \u041f\u0440\u0438 \u0440\u0430\u0437\u043c\u0435\u0449\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0438 \u0434\u043e \u0434\u0432\u0443\u0445 \u0434\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0439  \u043c\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0448\u0435 6 \u043b\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0438\u043c\u0435\u044e\u0449\u0438\u0445\u0441\u044f \u043a\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044f\u0445 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0438\u043c \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u043d\u043e . \u0414\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043a\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0438 \u0432 \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0435 \u043d\u0435 \u043f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043b\u044f\u044e\u0442\u0441\u044f.  \u041f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430: \u041f\u0440\u0435\u0434\u043e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043d\u0435  \u0432\u0437\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f.  \u041f\u043e\u0440\u044f\u0434\u043e\u043a \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f: \u0412 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0438\u0437\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0432 \u0441\u0440\u043e\u043a \u0434\u043e 18:00 \u0434\u0430\u0442\u044b \u0437\u0430\u0435\u0437\u0434\u0430 \u0448\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0444 \u043d\u0435 \u0432\u0437\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f. \u0412 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044b \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0438\u0437\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f \u0431\u0440\u043e\u043d\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f \u043f\u043e\u0437\u0434\u043d\u0435\u0435 \u044d\u0442\u043e\u0433\u043e \u0441\u0440\u043e\u043a\u0430 \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0432 \u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435 \u043d\u0435\u0437\u0430\u0435\u0437\u0434\u0430 \u0432\u0437\u0438\u043c\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f 100 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0446\u0435\u043d\u0442\u043e\u0432 \u043e\u0442  \u0441\u0442\u043e\u0438\u043c\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0438 \u043f\u0435\u0440\u0432\u043e\u0439 \u043d\u043e\u0447\u0438 \u043f\u0440\u043e\u0436\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f . '}, 'Guest': u'\u0421\u0418\u041b\u042c\u0412\u0415\u0421\u0422\u0420 \u0421\u0422\u0410\u041b\u041e\u041d\u0415', 'Smoking people': 'No', 'Daily rates': ['2018-02-20: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)', '2018-02-21: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)', '2018-02-22: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)', '2018-02-23: 1990.00 (Standard Rate)'], 'Number of guests': '2', 'Price details': [u'\u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0439 \u043d\u0430\u043b\u043e\u0433: 10.0RUB (included in room daily rates)'], 'Meal': u'\u041f\u0438\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u043d\u0435 \u0432\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u0442 \u0432 \u0446\u0435\u043d\u0443 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u043e\u0433\u043e \u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0430. '}, 'ChannelHotelId': '2360119', 'Channel reservation id': '1884282051', 'Commission': '1194.00'}
print(d)
print(json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False))
```

This should work. More info here: [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)