# How can I stringify a dictionary having a string with cyrillic symbols into a pretty JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desired output:

```
'{"a": "йцукен"}'
```

I tried this:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'a': 'йцукен'})
'{"a": "\\u0439\\u0446\\u0443\\u043a\\u0435\\u043d"}'
```

How can I avoid these U-codes and print normal symbols?

I am using Python 3.

Comment: Possibly related: [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ensure_ascii` keyword argument as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence):

```
json.dumps({'a': 'йцукен'}, ensure_ascii=False)
```