# How to convert dataframe to exact format needed for constant contact API?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, api-design

I have a dataframe with following data:

```
  email_addresses first_name last_name
0    test@test.com       test      test
1     Jane@Doe.com       Jane       Doe
2   John@Smith.com       John     Smith
```

I need to pass this data in the following format into the `'data'` parameter of constant contacts API. Format needs to be like this:

```
update_contact = 
{
    "import_data": [{
        "email_addresses": ["test@test.com"],
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "test"
    }, {
        "email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],
        "first_name": "Jane",
        "last_name": "Doe"
    }, {
        "email_addresses": ["John@Smith.com"],
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    }],
    "lists": ["1"]
}
```

As you can see I need to pass in string `'import_data'` and '`lists'` with square brackets around the `'lists_id'`.

I can pass the string while converting the dataframe to json like so:

```
update_contact = {"import_data" : update_contact.to_json(orient='records'),  "lists" : 1}
```

But the output is not what I am looking for. It comes out like this:

```
{'import_data': '[{"\\ufeffemail_addresses":"test@test.com","first_name":"test","last_name":"test"},{"\\ufeffemail_addresses":"Jane@Doe.com","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe"},{"\\ufeffemail_addresses":"John@Smith.com","first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"}]',
 'lists': 1}
```

The API I need to pass the `'update_contact'` looks like this:

```
headers = {

        'Authorization': 'Bearer x',
        'X-Originating-Ip': 'x',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        }

r = requests.post('https://api.constantcontact.com/v2/activities/addcontacts?api_key=x', headers=headers ,data = update_contact_now)
```

How do I get `to_json` to deliver me JSON that looks like this (for 100s of rows in dataframe)? :

```
update_contact = 
    {
        "import_data": [{
            "email_addresses": ["test@test.com"],
            "first_name": "test",
            "last_name": "test"
        }, {
            "email_addresses": ["Jane@Doe.com"],
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Doe"
        }, {
            "email_addresses": ["John@Smith.com"],
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith"
        }],
        "lists": ["1"]
    }
```

Edit:

Ran the line:

```
update_contact = {"import_data" : update_contact.to_dict(orient='records'),  "lists" : 1}
```

returned:

```
{'import_data': [{'first_name': 'test',
   'last_name': 'test',
   '\xef\xbb\xbfemail_addresses': 'test@test.com'},
  {'first_name': 'Jane',
   'last_name': 'Doe',
   '\xef\xbb\xbfemail_addresses': 'Jane@Doe.com'},
  {'first_name': 'John',
   'last_name': 'Smith',
   '\xef\xbb\xbfemail_addresses': 'John@Smith.com'}],
 'lists': 1072830671}
```

Edit2:

after running lines:

```
df['email_addresses'] = df['email_addresses'].apply(lambda x: [x])
update_contact = {"import_data" : df.to_dict(orient='records'),  "lists" : [1]}
print (update_contact)
```

I get the result:

```
{'import_data': [{u'email_address': 'bob.bob19955@gmail.com',
   u'first_name': u'bob',
   u'last_name': u'bob'},
  {u'email_address': 'tim@joe.com',
   u'first_name': u'tim',
   u'last_name': u'joe'},
  {u'email_address': 'sue1@sue1.com',
   u'first_name': u'sue1',
   u'last_name': u'sue1'},
  {u'email_address': 'tim3@test.com',
   u'first_name': u'tim3',
   u'last_name': u'test'},
  {u'email_address': 'paul@ryan.com',
   u'first_name': u'Paul ',
   u'last_name': u'Ryan'},
  {u'email_address': 'TG_FN_121717@TG_LN_121717.com',
   u'first_name': u'TG_FN_121717',
   u'last_name': u'TG_LN_121717'},
  {u'email_address': 'AS_FN_121717@AS_LN_121717.com',
   u'first_name': u'AS_FN_121717',
   u'last_name': u'AS_LN_121717'},
  {u'email_address': 'adamapple000@mailinator.com',
   u'first_name': u'Adam',
   u'last_name': u'Apple'},
  {u'email_address': 'brendabanana000@mailinator.com',
   u'first_name': u'Brenda',
   u'last_name': u'Banana'},
  {u'email_address': 'charlenecherry000@mailinator.com',
   u'first_name': u'Charlene',
   u'last_name': u'Cherry'},
  {u'email_address': 'donnadaquiri000@mailinator.com',
   u'first_name': u'Donna',
   u'last_name': u'Daquiri'}],
 'lists': [1]}
```

Not sure how to drop the `'u'`?

Edit3:

tried:

```
a = json.dumps(update_contact)
```

got this error:

```
u'[{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/0/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/0/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/1/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/1/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/2/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/2/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/3/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/3/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/4/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/4/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/5/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/5/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/6/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/6/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/7/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/7/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/8/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/8/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/9/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/9/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/10/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/10/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."},{"error_key":"json.field.invalid","error_message":"#/import_data/11/email_address: Property was found but is not permitted at this location."},{"error_key":"json.field.missing","error_message":"#/import_data/11/email_addresses: Property is required but not found."}]'
```

Final Edit:

These lines of code worked:

```
update_contact.rename(columns={'email_address': 'email_addresses'}, inplace=True)
    df['email_addresses'] = df['email_addresses'].apply(lambda x: [x])
    update_contact = {"import_data" : df.to_dict(orient='records'),  "lists" : [1]}
    a = json.dumps(update_contact,ensure_ascii=False)
    print (update_contact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for dictionary and last convert to `json`:

```
#remove \xef\xbb\xb
#https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4793
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding="utf-8-sig")
#df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()

df['email_addresses'] = df['email_addresses'].apply(lambda x: [x])
update_contact = {"import_data" : df.to_dict(orient='records'),  "lists" : [1]}
print (update_contact)
{'import_data': [{'email_addresses': ['test@test.com'], 
                  'first_name': 'test', 
                  'last_name': 'test'}, 
                 {'email_addresses': ['Jane@Doe.com'], 
                  'first_name': 'Jane', 
                  'last_name': 'Doe'},
                 {'email_addresses': ['John@Smith.com'], 
                  'first_name': 'John', 
                  'last_name': 'Smith'}],
  'lists': [1]}
```

Comment: Spoke to soon, after clearning memory. I reran your line. see edit for issue:

Comment: the issue is also I need to put square brackets around the email addresses and list_ids

Comment: your answer brings me very close, how do I drop the 'u' in the edit2 I made above?

Comment: @RustyShackleford - I think need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18337754/2901002)

Comment: literally just tried that line and passed into API got error in edit:

Comment: do you think the error in the edit, could be because of placement of the column headers?

Comment: tried your link, but getting same error. I think it has to do with placement

Comment: @RustyShackleford What about `json.dumps(update_contact, ensure_ascii=False)` ?

Comment: yep exactly that line. I also inserted the missing email address and got same error message

Comment: @RustyShackleford - Not easy for me, because cannot test. the simpliest should be switch to `python 3`.

Comment: the issues was I had to convert 'email_address' to 'email_addresses' and it worked!