# Tell geojson to save data as UTF8?

Tags: python, geojson

I can't figure out why geojson saves data in that format (UTF16?) so that "François" ends up as "Fran\u00e7ois" when calling geojson.dump() to save data back to disk.

Any idea?

```
import geojson
from geojson import LineString, Point, Feature, FeatureCollection, dump
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

with open('input.geojson', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

for track in gj['features']:
    #NO DIFF with open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    with open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+') as f:
        dump(track, f, indent=2)

        #UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2194' in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
        #dump(track, f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

        #NOT DEFINED
        #dumps(track, f, indent=2)

        #AttributeError: encode
        #dump(track.encode("utf-8"), f, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Thank you.

--

Edit :

I followed the other thread, and tried several things, but still cannot maintain the original text.

```
        INPUTFILE = 'input.geojson'

        with open(INPUTFILE, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            gj = geojson.load(f)

        for track in gj['features']:
            #Bad : \u00e0 instead of "à"
            ##with open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+') as f:
                ##dump(track, f, indent=2)

            #Bad : "Ã " instead of "à"
        ##    with io.open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
        ##        dump(track, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)

        ##    with io.open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
        ##        #NameError: name 'dumps' is not defined
        ##        data = dumps(track, ensure_ascii=False)
        ##        # unicode(data) auto-decodes data to unicode if str
        ##        json_file.write(unicode(data))

            #Bad : "Ã " instead of "à"
        ##    with codecs.open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        ##        dump(track, f, ensure_ascii=False)

    ##    with codecs.open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+', 'utf-8') as fp:
    ##        #NameError: name 'dumps' is not defined
    ##        fp.write(dumps(track, ensure_ascii=False))

    #Bad : "Ã " instead of "à"
##    with io.open(track['properties']['name'][0] + '.geojson', 'a+', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
##        json.dump(track, json_file, ensure_ascii=False)

            break
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Comment: JSON allows for both escaped or non-escaped non-ascii characters, and since `dump` is a wrapper around the standard json function, they are stored this way. Are these files going to be read by humans? If not, is there a reason for you to care about the way it's stored?

Comment: Yes, I'd rather have readable data.