# Converting a dictionary to json having persian characters

Tags: python, json, dictionary, persian

Here is some code of mine, I'm trying to convert a dictionary to json having Persian characters but I get question marks instead of characters. My dictionary looks like this:

```
bycommunity("0": [{"60357": "این یک پیام است"}] )

with open('data.json', 'wb') as f:
f.write(json.dumps(bycommunity).encode("utf-8"))
```

the result is :

```
{"0": [{"60357": "?????? ??? ??? ???? ???????? ??????"}]}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data = {"0": [{"60357": "این یک پیام است"}]} 
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

and also check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence) for more details

Comment: Please, don't name the variable `dict` and thus hide the built-in `dict`. Name it e.g. `data`, or whatever.

Comment: You also don’t need to explicitly close a file that’s opened using `with`. And you can use `json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=True)` to negate having to use `jsonData` variable.

Comment: It helps to explain the change you've made as opposed to just correct it.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonf.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```