# How to write exact wordings of unicode characters into a file?

Tags: python, xlrd

when I want to write "සිවු අවුරුදු පාටමාලාව" with the exact wording into a `json` file using python3.6, but instead `\u0dc3\u0dd2\u0dc3\u0dd4\u0db1\u0dca\u0da7 \u0dc3\u0dd2\u0dc0\u0dd4` is written into the json file.

I read an excel using `xlrd` and write to using `open()`.

```
import xlrd 
import json

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx',encoding_override='utf-8') 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    data = json.dump(outerdata,outfile,ensure_ascii=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do this in Python with the escape string you report:

```
>>> print ("\u0dc3\u0dd2\u0dc3\u0dd4\u0db1\u0dca\u0da7 \u0dc3\u0dd2\u0dc0\u0dd4")
සිසුන්ට සිවු
```

you will see that the escapes do render as the characters you want. These are two different representations of the same data. Both representations are valid in JSON. But you are using `json.dump()` and you have specified `ensure_ascii=True`. That tells `json.dump()` that you *want* the representation with escapes. That is what `ascii` means: only the printable characters between `chr(32)` and `chr(126)`. Change that to `ensure_ascii=False`.

But because you are now no longer writing pure ascii to your output file `data.json`, you need to specify an encoding when you open it:

```
with open("data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    data = json.dump(outerdata,outfile,ensure_ascii=False)
```

This will make your JSON file look the way you want it to look.

Comment: When i set ensure_ascii=False then it throws an error. UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 3-8: cha
racter maps to <undefined>

Comment: Set the encoding of the file to something other than the default, which is ascii. See edit.

Comment: thanks @BoarGules ,i tried to achieve the result many days.you saved me...