# How to print json pretty with utf 8 in the command line?

Tags: json, utf-8, command-line-interface

I am trying to print a json text pretty in the command line,

```
{"en":"surprise","de":"Überraschung"}
```

The command `python -m json.tool` prints it pretty, but with \u...:

```
$ echo '{"en":"surprise","de":"Überraschung"}' | python -m json.tool
{
    "de": "\u00dcberraschung",
    "en": "surprise"
}
```

Could you please advise how to solve it in the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Comment: Tangentially, also lose the [useless use of `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: [`json.tool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/json/tool.py) does not expose an option for this; but requiring a solution which does not involve programming makes your question off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway.

Comment: Thank you for hints. I do not insist on this python solution with `json.tool`.  It could be another way. Just I am looking for a solution how to print a json output pretty and with normal text. And `cat` is just for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

```
echo '{"en":"surprise","de":"Überraschung"}' | jq
{
  "en": "surprise",
  "de": "Überraschung"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now we can do it with option `--no-ensure-ascii`

```sh
$ echo '{"en":"surprise","de":"Überraschung"}' | python -m json.tool --no-ensure-ascii
{
    "en": "surprise",
    "de": "Überraschung"
}
```

tested on python 3.9.9