# How to set up Google Chrome Extension Native Messaging and sending parameters to native host properly?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am developing a chrome extension and I need to implement a feature that allows to launch an .exe on button click AND pass user entered parameters to that .exe.

Feature details:
User selects file and clicks on a **button** -> button triggers prompt menu, getting input from user -> if user provides input extension launches .exe file, passing user entered input to .exe's stdio stream -> .exe reads stdin and saves user entered input to txt file -> (optional) .exe sends success message to extension.

The problem is it does not work as expected and i have no idea what did i do wrong :(

Here is what i did and my results:

**Button onClick logic:**

*content.js*

```
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        allSelected = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-selected="true"]')
        console.log(allSelected.length)
        let allFIles = []
        allSelected.forEach(element => {
            // Get the parent element
            const parentElement = element.parentNode;
            
            // Check if the parent element has the data-id attribute
            if (parentElement && parentElement.hasAttribute('data-id')) {
                // Retrieve the value of the data-id attribute
                const dataIdValue = parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
                console.log('Data ID value:', dataIdValue);
                allFIles.push(dataIdValue)
            } else {
                console.log('Parent element does not have a data-id attribute');
            }
        });
        const userInput = window.prompt(`You selected ${allFIles.length} files. Please, provide info on these files below.`, '');

        // Check if the user entered something
        if (userInput !== null) {
            // User clicked OK and entered some text
            console.log('User input:', userInput);
            allInfo = {"fileIds": allFIles, "newValues": userInput}
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'connectNative', data: allInfo});
        } else {
            // User clicked Cancel or closed the prompt dialog
            console.log('User canceled input.');
        }
    });
```

In my *background.js* file I tried using both chrome.runtime.connectNative+port.postMessage or chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage. Trough a lot of trial and error I came up with this block of code that seems to work (to some extent):

*background.js*

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('Message received:', request);

  if (request.action === 'connectNative') {

    console.log("try");
    let port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('com.google_drive.edit_description'); 

    port.postMessage({filesToEdit: request["data"]})
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
      console.log("Message from native messaging host:", message);

    });
  }
});
```

I created com.my_extension.new_feature folder in NativeMessagingHost and provided full path to native-apps/editInfo.json

*editInfo.json*

```
{
    "name": "com.my_extension.new_feature",
    "description": "My Application",
    "path": "new_feature.exe",
    "type": "stdio",
    "allowed_origins": ["chrome-extension://<passed my_extension's id>/"]
  }
```

I added nativeMessaging permissions to manifest.json. So far so good.
Then i created my .exe file from Python script (this is my primary programming language)

*new_feature.py*

```
import sys
import json
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
                    filename='new_feature.log',
                    filemode='a')


def main():
    logging.info("Started")

    input_data = sys.stdin.read()

    logging.info("Read stdin")
    logging.info(f"Input data: {input_data}")

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(input_data)

    logging.info("Wrote to file")
    send_message({"message": "Success"})



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

It looks like everything should be fine now, but this is what happens:
On **button** click my *new_feature.exe* is triggered. It writes to .log file `15-Feb-24 18:51:34 - root - INFO - Started` and then it does nothing! I tried setting setTimeout before `port.postMessage` in *background.js* (just in case there are some time-related problems)- nothing changed, same results. But while experimenting I noticed that when I reload extension from in chrome://extensions/ it seems to "release" this part of code `input_data = sys.stdin.read()`, and successfuly runs the rest of the code, writing to .log

```
15-Feb-24 18:58:10 - root - INFO - Read stdin
15-Feb-24 18:58:10 - root - INFO - Input data: 6  {"filesToEdit":{"fileIds":[<fileIds>],"newValues":"<newValues>"}}
15-Feb-24 18:58:10 - root - INFO - Wrote to file
```

I don`t understand why this is happening and this does not solve my problem - I am not going to reload extension every time I want to use this feature. I read a lot of different answers here as well as everywhere else, including asking chatGPT. Nothing seemed to work.

Then I accidentally didn't comment the rest of the code when trying to send message from .exe to extension (why not...) AND IT WORKED. I have no idea why, here is the full code that reads stdin and writes to .log file with no problems:

*new_feature.py*

```
import sys
import json
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
                    filename='edit_gd_description.log',
                    filemode='a')

def send_message(message):
    sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(message))
    sys.stdout.flush()


def main():
    logging.info("Started")

    send_message({"message": "Waiting for input"})

    input_data = sys.stdin.read()

    logging.info("Read stdin")
    logging.info(f"Input data: {input_data}")

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(input_data)

    logging.info("Wrote to file")
    send_message({"message": "Success"})



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
```

This logs `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Error when communicating with the native messaging host.` to *background.js* console, but the .exe works well, getting right input from stdin that extesion sends, and writing this input to .log and .txt.

I would like to know **why is that happening, what did I do wrong? How can i make .exe send messages to extension?**

Thank you for any help or ideas!

Comment: Your python code is not reading stdin correctly, see [this example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging/host/native-messaging-example-host).

Comment: @wOxxOm Google's Python Native Messaging host code is broken, too. On Linux, in general, there is no `/usr/bin/python`, Python 2X is deprecated. We have to use `python3`. Additionally Google's sample does not process up to 1 MB from the client. The GoogleChromeSample folks closed the issue after banning me but never fixed the bug https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/issues/805 MDN published working code https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/issues/509. Working Python example https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_python.py.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your working code based on https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_python.py. Native Messaging host uses a loop to keep the host active and not exit.

Nowhere in your code do you parse the message length, which happens in the below code in `getMessage` and `encodeMessage`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S python3 -u
# https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging
# https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/pull/157
# Note that running python with the `-u` flag is required on Windows,
# in order to ensure that stdin and stdout are opened in binary, rather
# than text, mode.

import sys
import json
import struct
import traceback
import logging

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S',
                    filename='new_feature.log',
                    filemode='a')

try:
    # Python 3.x version
    # Read a message from stdin and decode it.
    def getMessage():
        rawLength = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)
        if len(rawLength) == 0:
            sys.exit(0)
        messageLength = struct.unpack('@I', rawLength)[0]
        message = sys.stdin.buffer.read(messageLength).decode('utf-8')
        return json.loads(message)

    # Encode a message for transmission,
    # given its content.
    def encodeMessage(messageContent):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/56563264
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage
        # To get the most compact JSON representation, you should specify 
        # (',', ':') to eliminate whitespace.
        encodedContent = json.dumps(messageContent, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')
        encodedLength = struct.pack('@I', len(encodedContent))
        return {'length': encodedLength, 'content': encodedContent}

    # Send an encoded message to stdout
    def sendMessage(encodedMessage):
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['length'])
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(encodedMessage['content'])
        sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
        
    while True:
        receivedMessage = getMessage()
        logging.info("Started")
        logging.info("Read stdin")
        logging.info(f"Input data: {receivedMessage}")
        with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(receivedMessage))
        logging.info("Wrote to file")
        sendMessage(encodeMessage({"message": "Success"}))

except Exception as e:
    sys.stdout.buffer.flush()
    sys.stdin.buffer.flush()
    # https://discuss.python.org/t/how-to-read-1mb-of-input-from-stdin/22534/14
    with open('nm_python.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)
    sys.exit(0)
```