# How to read list of JSON formatted dictionaries of Japanese and not insert new characters?

Tags: python, json

I'm scraping data from ~500 `.js` files, all of them are formatted like this:

```
dict[0]=[{"some_key": "<b>名詞</b>", "another_key": "modification"}, {"some_key": "<b>名詞</b>", "another_key": "idea"}]
```

My code looks like this:

```
my_file = open(filename, 'r',encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
obj = my_file.read()
try:
    my_indexer_left = obj.replace('[', 'xxx', 1).find('[')
    my_indexer_right = obj.rfind(']')
    new_obj = obj[my_indexer_left:my_indexer_right+1]
```

And after this `new_obj` is created I can't convert it out of a `string`.

I tried `list(new_obj)`:

```
new_list_obj = list(new_obj)
for item in new_list_obj:
    print(item)
```

And while `print(type(new_list_obj))` tells me `list`, the `print` statement prints out one character at a time.

I've tried several other things along these lines to get this to work.

The closest I came was referencing the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence) to come up with the following:

```
j = json.dumps(new_obj,ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8').decode()
```

But when I `print(j)` all of the quotation marks (`"`) are turned into `\"` and when I `print(type(j))` it says `str`.

I want to be able to read these files, iterate over all the `dictionary` (`json`) objects and access the `keys` and `values`.

Comment: is the file a json file?  if so, you can read it into python using the `json` module.

Comment: @James, it's in a JavaScript file and I have been trying to read it using the `json` module but for some reason it stays as a `string` and I can't get it to turn into a `dict`

Comment: JavaScript is not the same as JSON.  It will have lines of programming code that will not be parsable as JSON.  Can you post the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse data in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-to-parse-data-in-json)

Comment: @mkrieger1, author has JSON nested in a .js file.  This is a bit more complicated than just parsing a JSON file.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I saw the question you referenced as a duplicate when researching how to accomplish this and it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: using list "[" or "]" in string to manipulate as string make me cry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the file you posted, it is JavaScript file that assigns a JSON array to the `0` index of a variable called `dict`.  My guess is that each of the files is assigned to the next index of dict.

You can try to parse this by reading in the file as a string, strip off the extra JavaScript pieces, split on the first `=` sign, and then pass the rest to the `json.loads` function.

```py
import json
with open('000.js', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    raw_str = fp.read()
    raw_str = raw_str.strip().strip(';')
    raw_str = raw_str.split('=', 1)[-1]
    data = json.loads(raw_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the example file you uploaded, it can be done as follows in two simple steps:

1. Strip `dict[i]=` prefix and `;` suffix from file contents (using a regular expression to generalize *i*).
2. Parse resulting data as JSON.

```
import json
import re

def parse_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.read()

    json_text = re.match(r'dict\[\d+\]=(.*);', data).group(1)
    return json.loads(json_text)
```