# Dump Chinese data into a json file

Tags: json, unicode, python-3.6

I am falling on a problem, while dumping a chinese data (non-latin language data) into a json file.

I am trying to store list into a `json` file with the following code;

```
with open("file_name.json","w",encoding="utf8") as file:
    json.dump(edits,file)
```

It will dumped without any errors.
When i am viewing a file, it will look like this,

```
[{sentence: \u5979\u7d30\u5c0f\u8072\u5c0d\u6211\u8aaa\uff1a\u300c\u6211\u501f\u4f60\u4e00\u679d\u925b\u7b46\u3002\u300d}...]
```

And I also tried out, without encoding option.

```
with open("file_name.json","w") as file:
    json.dump(edits,file)
```

My question is, why my json file look like this, and how to dump my json file with having **chinese** string instead of **unicode** string.
Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks : )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs for [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump).

Specifically, it has a switch `ensure_ascii` that if set to `False` should make the function not escape the characters.

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is false, these characters will be output as-is.

Comment: Exactly!! I did the same on yesterday.Thank You