# How to consume message from kafka which was produced by kafka-python?

Tags: java, python-3.x, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I would like to get help with kafka.

Is it possible to consume utf8(Japanese) messages using `kafka-console-consumer.sh` which was produced by [kafka-python](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html) ?

- kafka-python code

```
self._client = KafkaProducer(\
                    bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,\
                    api_version=api_version,\
                    value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))

for message in data:
    self._client.send(topic, message)
```

- kafka-cosole-consumer.sh

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server msk.amazonaws.com:9092 --topic meetings --from-beginning --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.BytesDeserializer
```

- Result

```
"uuid": "d/U55wRdSj60yJBcYVpt8A==", "id": 4459052115, "topic": "\x5Cu6e21\x5Cu8fba \x5Cu88d5\x5Cu306e\x5Cu30d1\x5Cu30fc\x5Cu30bd\x5Cu30ca\x5Cu30eb\x5Cu30df\x5Cu30fc\x5Cu30c6\x5Cu30a3\x5Cu30f3\x5Cu30b0\x5Cu30eb\x5Cu30fc\x5Cu30e0", "host": "\x5Cu6e21\x5Cu8fba \x5Cu88d5", "email": "y-watanabe@creationline.com", "user_type": "\x5Cu30e9\x5Cu30a4\x5Cu30bb\x5Cu30f3\x5Cu30b9\x5Cu6e08\x5Cu307f", "start_time": "2020-11-03T10:36:29Z", "end_time": "", "duration": "", "participants": 1, "has_pstn": false, "has_voip": false, "has_3rd_party_audio": false, "has_video": false, "has_screen_share": false, "has_recording": false, "has_sip": false, "dept": ""}
```

It seems that Japanese string(utf-8) is not deserialized correctly. It is **corrupted**.

I am trying to send message through below route.

```
producer(kafka-python) -> AWS MSK (2.4.1.1) -> consumer(kafka-console-consumer.sh)
```

Comment: It doesnt look corrupted to me

Answer (score 1):

I had couple things that I was not understanding correctly.

1. [ByteDeserializer](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/2.4.0/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/BytesDeserializer.html) converts Byte objects into Byte type in Java. So as @codeflush.dev had said, I am seeing correct behaviour.

> Deserialize a record value from a byte array into a value or object.

2. I was missing the fact that [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) escapes non-ascii characters .This is controlled by *ensure_ascii* option.

> If ensure_ascii is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If ensure_ascii is false, these characters will be output as-is.

By setting *ensure_ascii* to `False` then converting into *byte* , solved the issue.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8'))
```

Relates to

[Saving utf-8 texts in json.dumps as UTF8, not as \u escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence/18337754)