# UTF-8 CSV file converted to JSON loses special character

Tags: json, csv, converters, file-conversion

I am using a CSV to JSON converter where I am specifying both, input and output files to be UTF-8 format, however, the output file is corrupt.  Below is a sample of data in CVS and in JSON:

CSV:  "1993885","Rejean",,"Lacroix","gf.employee@xxxx.xxx","Rejean.Lacroix",,"15-B Principale nord","St-Bruno de Guigues (Quebec)",,"St-Bruno de Guigues (Quebec)","QC","CA","J0Z 2G0","Sorting, Packing and Stacking","Male","Prép.table triage automatique","Active","Employee",19491121,19760804

JSON: {
"\ufeffEmployeeID": "1993885",
"FirstName": "Rejean",
"MiddleName": "",
"LastName": "Lacroix",
"PersonalEmailAddress": "gf.employee@xxxx.xxx\n\n",
"LoginID": "Rejean.Lacroix",
"": "Sorting, Packing and Stacking",
"HomeAddressLine1": "15-B Principale nord",
"HomeAddressLine2": "St-Bruno de Guigues (Quebec)",
"HomeAddressLine3": "",
"HomeAddressCity": "St-Bruno de Guigues (Quebec)\n\n\n",
"HomeAddressState": "QC",
"HomeAddressCountry": "CA",
"HomeAddressPostalCode": "J0Z 2G0",
"Gender": "Male",
"PositionTitle": "Pr\u00e9p.table triage automatique",
"Status": "Active",
"Shift": "Employee\n\n",
"DateOfBirth": "19491121",
"DateOfHire": "19760804"
}

Below is the code that I am using:

'''
import csv
import json
import time

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
jsonArray = []

```
#read csv file
with open(csvFilePath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
    #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

    #convert each csv row into python dict
    for row in csvReader:
        #add this python dict to json array
        jsonArray.append(row)

#convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
    jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
    jsonf.write(jsonString)
```

csvFilePath = r'scoopsoft_dump.csv'
jsonFilePath = r'scoopsoft_dump.json'

start = time.perf_counter()
csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f"Conversion 100.000 rows completed successfully in {finish - start:0.4f} seconds")
'''

Comment: What do you mean by special character, like é in Prép.table?

Comment: Also, I see \ufeff in your JSON, which means there’s a BOM at the beginning of your CSV. Use encoding=“utf-8-bom” when you open the CSV file.

Comment: And, does this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18337407, answer your question?