# Python format json for saving to file

Tags: python, json, dataframe, dictionary

My data looks like this:

```
    Key1: [Key2:[{},{},...{}]]
```

The code something like this:

```
    dict_={}
    dict_['Key2']=all_items
    dict_fin={}
    dict_fin['Ke1']=[dict_]
    df=pd.DataFrame(dict_fin)
    df.to_json(filepath, orient="records",lines=True)
```

I would like to have saved json like this:

```
{ "Key1": [{"Key2" : [{},{},...,{}]}] }
```

Instead, I get it like this:

```
{ "Key1": {"Key2" : [{},{},...,{}]} }
```

Comment: why use pandas DataFrame? Are you aware of `json` module and its `.dump` method for saving a dictionary directly to json file?

Comment: cool, json worked fine. I need final encoding of the file UTF-16 LE BOM. How do I set encoding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-with-json-dumps-as-utf-8-not-as-a-u-escape-sequence

Answer (score 2):

Use the `json` [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) from the Python standard library:

```
import json

outer_dict = { }
some_list = [{"inner_key":"inner_value"}, {"inner_key_2":"inner_value_2"}]
outer_dict["Key1"] = some_list
json.dumps(outer_dict)
```

Will give you:
`'{"Key1": [{"inner_key": "inner_value"}, {"inner_key_2": "inner_value_2"}]}'`

Answer (score -1):

I believe the errors is on the line `dict_fin['Ke1']=[dict_]`. You had assigned `dict_['Key2']` instead:

```
dict_={}
dict_['Key2']=all_items
dict_fin={}
dict_fin['Ke1']=[dict_['Key2']]
df=pd.DataFrame(dict_fin)
df.to_json(filepath, orient="records",lines=True)
```